# X Error of failed request: BadMatch on X_ShmPutImage | Major opcode 130 | Minor opcode 3

Tags: c, opengl, x11, mesa, glx

Since my last system upgrade on Gentoo, I'm not able to run some code of mine: [window_management.c](https://github.com/DenisSalem/DStudio/blob/dsandgrains/src/window_management.c) which was working without any warnings nor errors before the upgrade.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

#include "common.h"
#include "extensions.h"
#include "text_pointer.h"
#include "window_management.h"

static void (*cursor_position_callback)(int xpos, int ypos) = 0;
void (*mouse_button_callback)(int xpos, int ypos, int button, int action) = 0;

#ifdef DSTUDIO_RELY_ON_X11

#define DSTUDIO_X11_INPUT_MASKS \
    ExposureMask | \
    KeyPressMask | \
    KeyReleaseMask | \
    ButtonPressMask | \
    ButtonReleaseMask | \
    VisibilityChangeMask

#define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
#define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092

typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);

static int ctx_error_occurred = 0;
static int window_alive = 1;
static int refresh_all = 1;
static Display              *display = NULL;
static Window               window;
static XVisualInfo          * visual_info;
static Colormap             color_map;
static XEvent               x_event;
static XEvent               x_sent_expose_event;
static GLXContext           opengl_context;
static int visual_attribs[] = {
      GLX_X_RENDERABLE    , True,
      GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE   , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
      GLX_RENDER_TYPE     , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
      GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE   , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
      GLX_RED_SIZE        , 8,
      GLX_GREEN_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_BLUE_SIZE       , 8,
      GLX_ALPHA_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_DEPTH_SIZE      , 24,
      GLX_STENCIL_SIZE    , 8,
      GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER    , True,
      None
};

static int glx_major, glx_minor;
static unsigned int keyboard_chars_map_mode = 0;

static int ctx_error_handler( Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev ) {
    (void) dpy;
    (void) ev;
    ctx_error_occurred = 1;
    return 0;
}

static void creating_color_map(XVisualInfo * vi, Window * root_window, XSetWindowAttributes * swa) {
    color_map = XCreateColormap(display, *root_window, vi->visual, AllocNone);
    swa->colormap = color_map;
    swa->background_pixmap = None ;
    swa->border_pixel      = 0;
    swa->event_mask        = ExposureMask | StructureNotifyMask |PointerMotionMask;
}

void destroy_context() {
    glXDestroyContext(display, opengl_context);
    XDestroyWindow(display, window);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}

static void get_visual_info(GLXFBConfig * best_frame_buffer_config) {
    int fbcount;
    int best_frame_buffer_config_index = -1;
    int worst_fbc = -1;
    int best_num_samp = -1;
    int worst_num_samp = 999;

    GLXFBConfig * frame_buffer_config = glXChooseFBConfig(display, DefaultScreen(display), visual_attribs, &fbcount);
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(frame_buffer_config)

    for (int i=0; i<fbcount; ++i) {
        visual_info = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, frame_buffer_config[i] );
        if (visual_info) {
            int samp_buf, samples;
            glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, frame_buffer_config[i], GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &samp_buf );
            glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, frame_buffer_config[i], GLX_SAMPLES       , &samples  );
            #ifdef DSTUDIO_DEBUG
                printf("Matching fbconfig %d, visual ID 0x%2lux: SAMPLE_BUFFERS = %d, SAMPLES = %d\n", i, visual_info->visualid, samp_buf, samples );
            #endif
            if ( best_frame_buffer_config_index < 0 || (samp_buf && samples > best_num_samp)) {
                best_frame_buffer_config_index = i; 
                best_num_samp = samples;
            }
            if ( worst_fbc < 0 || !samp_buf || samples < worst_num_samp ) {
                worst_fbc = i;
                worst_num_samp = samples;
            }
        }
        XFree(visual_info);
    }

    *best_frame_buffer_config = frame_buffer_config[ best_frame_buffer_config_index ];
    XFree( frame_buffer_config );

    // Get a visual
    visual_info = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, *best_frame_buffer_config );
    #ifdef DSTUDIO_DEBUG
        printf( "Chosen visual ID = 0x%lux\n", visual_info->visualid );
    #endif
}

void init_context(const char * window_name, int width, int height) {
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(XInitThreads());
    int (*old_handler)(Display*, XErrorEvent*) = XSetErrorHandler(&ctx_error_handler);
    Window root_window;
    XSetWindowAttributes swa;
    XSizeHints * size_hints;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(display)

    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(glXQueryVersion( display, &glx_major, &glx_minor ))
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_FAILURE( glx_major == 1  &&  (glx_minor < 3))
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_FAILURE( glx_major < 1 )

    GLXFBConfig best_frame_buffer_config;
    get_visual_info(&best_frame_buffer_config);
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(visual_info)

    root_window = RootWindow(display, visual_info->screen);
    creating_color_map(visual_info, &root_window, &swa);

    window = XCreateWindow(display, root_window, 0, 0, width, height, 0, visual_info->depth, InputOutput, visual_info->visual, CWBorderPixel|CWColormap|CWEventMask, &swa);

    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_NULL(window)

    size_hints = XAllocSizeHints();
    size_hints->flags = PMinSize | PMaxSize;
    size_hints->min_width = width;
    size_hints->min_height = height;
    size_hints->max_width = width;
    size_hints->max_height = height;

    XSetWMSizeHints(display, window, size_hints, XA_WM_NORMAL_HINTS);
    Atom delWindow = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display , window, &delWindow, 1);

    XSelectInput(display, window, DSTUDIO_X11_INPUT_MASKS | ButtonMotionMask);
    XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat (display, 1, NULL);

    XFree(visual_info);
    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XStoreName(display, window, window_name);

    // Begin OpenGL context creation

    const char *glx_exts = glXQueryExtensionsString(display, DefaultScreen( display ));
    glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
    glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );

    if ( !is_extension_supported( glx_exts, "GLX_ARB_create_context" ) || !glXCreateContextAttribsARB ) {
        #ifdef DSTUDIO_DEBUG
            printf("glXCreateContextAttribsARB() not found. Using old-style GLX context.\n");
        #endif
        opengl_context = glXCreateNewContext( display, best_frame_buffer_config, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, 1);
    }
    else {
        int context_attribs[] = {
            GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
            GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,   GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
            //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
            None
        };

        opengl_context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(display, best_frame_buffer_config, 0, 1, context_attribs);
    }

    // Sync to ensure any errors generated are processed.
    XSync(display, 0);
    DSTUDIO_EXIT_IF_FAILURE( ctx_error_occurred && opengl_context == 0)
    XSetErrorHandler(old_handler);

    #ifdef DSTUDIO_DEBUG
        if (!glXIsDirect(display, opengl_context)) {
            printf("Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Direct GLX rendering context obtained\n");
        }
    #endif
    glXMakeCurrent( display, window, opengl_context );
}

void send_expose_event() {
    memset(&x_sent_expose_event, 0, sizeof(x_sent_expose_event));
    x_sent_expose_event.xexpose.serial = clock();
    x_sent_expose_event.type = Expose;
    x_sent_expose_event.xexpose.send_event = 1;
    x_sent_expose_event.xexpose.display = display;
    XSendEvent(display, window, 1, ExposureMask, &x_sent_expose_event);
    XFlush(display);
}

void swap_window_buffer() {
    glXSwapBuffers(display, window);
}

#endif
```

My code crash when calling glXSwapBuffers() with the following output:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_ShmPutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  52
  Current serial number in output stream:  53
```

I noticed that glxgears have similar issue on my box, but doesn't crash. The error came out only when exiting glxgears and produce the following:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_ShmPutImage)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x2600002
  Serial number of failed request:  912
  Current serial number in output stream:  913
```

I first tried to recompile my kernel, xorg-drivers, xorg-server, mesa and xf86-video-intel (Yeah I'm on an Intel third generation) without any progress.

Since glxgears run "fine" and even if it might be a bug in the above packages, maybe there is something i'm doing wrong here.

**EDIT 1**: As suggested in comments, I've compiled my code with **-fsanitize=address** and got the following output:

```
=================================================================
==8391==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 2048 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669d878 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10c878)
    #1 0x55c7722b61e1 in load_shader /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/ui.c:357
    #2 0x55c7722b3fb9 in create_shader_program /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/ui.c:113
    #3 0x55c7722ab509 in ui_thread /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/dsandgrains/ui.c:305
    #4 0x7fa7462bf457 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x8457)

Direct leak of 600 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669d878 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10c878)
    #1 0x7fa745c9371e in __getdelim (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x7571e)
    #2 0x55c7722af580 in get_proc_memory_usage /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/fileutils.c:119
    #3 0x55c7722b1a42 in update_system_usage /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/system_usage.c:71
    #4 0x7fa7462bf457 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x8457)

Direct leak of 600 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669d878 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10c878)
    #1 0x7fa745c9371e in __getdelim (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x7571e)
    #2 0x55c7722af580 in get_proc_memory_usage /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/fileutils.c:119
    #3 0x55c7722b196f in update_system_usage /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/system_usage.c:56
    #4 0x7fa7462bf457 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x8457)

Direct leak of 120 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669d878 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10c878)
    #1 0x7fa745c9371e in __getdelim (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x7571e)
    #2 0x55c7722afa87 in set_physical_memory /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/fileutils.c:169
    #3 0x55c7722a693b in main /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/dsandgrains/main.c:36
    #4 0x7fa745c41e6a in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x23e6a)

Direct leak of 80 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669da68 in __interceptor_calloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10ca68)
    #1 0x55c7722b7e7b in init_context /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/window_management.c:172
    #2 0x55c7722ab4b5 in ui_thread /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/dsandgrains/ui.c:295
    #3 0x7fa7462bf457 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x8457)

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa74669d878 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libasan.so.5+0x10c878)
    #1 0x55c7722b5242 in init_ui_elements /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/ui.c:246
    #2 0x55c7722a96a0 in init_ui /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/dsandgrains/ui.c:154
    #3 0x55c7722ab513 in ui_thread /home/http/dev/github/DStudio/src/dsandgrains/ui.c:307
    #4 0x7fa7462bf457 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x8457)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 3464 byte(s) leaked in 14 allocation(s).
```

Comment: Have you run your code under Valgrind or similar?

Comment: I did not try anything with Valgrind, but I give a try with gdb without getting more information. 

I put a break on glXSwapBuffers, and try to step on. It immediately crash with the known error.

I don't know well Valgrind. May you be more specific on how I should run my app with Valgrind?

Comment: Maybe easier than Valgrind would be to compile your code using flag `-fsanitize=address` and see if there are any errors when running after that.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Done. Indeed there is some errors, but I don't understand how memory leaks may affect the program in other ways than consuming memory for nothing?

Comment: Leaks aren't an issue in this case, but Address Sanitizer can also find other types of issues, but seems that in this case it didn't, so that's good.

Comment: While this is issue surely put in evidence that there is some inconsistencies with my code. I've noticed that older code from other projects of mine doesn't work anymore with GLFW3 as well. Failling the same way when calling glfwSwapBuffers. As I said everything began from my last system upgrade. I strongly suspect now that there is something wrong with my video drivers and/or mesa implementation.
I keep looking forward for answers.

Comment: Well my issue is fixed. I was using mesa-19.3.0 and I downgraded to 19.1.8  which is the recommanded version for Gentoo at this time.

Comment: Downgrading from mesa 19.3.0 to 19.2.7 fixes the issue for me too.